# Get first Https response using guzzleHttp - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm using [GuzzleHttp](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#using-responses) for get a status code from a webpage
the problem is that apparently the library waits for the whole page to respond to get the status.

Why?

Because when I try to get the status code of a URL using guzzleHttp, the first response (in my browser) is the expected 404 error that I need, however later there are more responses with code 200

Finally the library returns the code 200 instead of the 404 that I am expecting

for example

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$value = "jsjdhjfhejdhwudehe";

$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://instagram.com/']);
    $response = $client->request('GET', $value . '/', ['allow_redirects' => ['max' => 2], ['track_redirects' => true]]);
dd($response);
```

my $response is:

```
^ GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response {#1548 ▼
  -reasonPhrase: "OK"
  -statusCode: 200
  -headers: array:30 [▶]
  -headerNames: array:30 [▶]
  -protocol: "1.1"
  -stream: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream {#1542 ▶}
}
```

but In the browser, the first response is 404

Note: If I set "allow_redirects" to false, it always gives 405 error.
If I set a maximum number of redirects to 1, I end up getting the error "Will not follow more than 1 redirects"

[image]

guzzleHttp version: 7.4.1

Comment: test your script with your own domain. the correct response is the 405 from the start. Instagram has some parsing/crawling protection in place that represent wild cards in this problem of yours since dont know how many are implemented.

Comment: thanks, at the moment I have discovered that by concatenating /?__a=1 after the username, I can get a JSON of the accounts, so with this I can get 404 errors :)